# Heroku deploy getting stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails app in Heroku using `git push heroku master`

But an error is being catched by this command, here's the log.

```
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.522637 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/1-c7a401b57d70b46b42984b290478bf1e.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.524674 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/1@2x-02460fd176a2aa596716268a565ad580.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.531627 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/2-e7a5d29ca42b0b0afc23a530fec46d4b.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.533755 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/2@2x-47a5569c04f5ec493170bf4e3e4f3266.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.540151 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/3-ad577a926eafa5391f55e47bf0b6232a.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.551793 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/3@2x-8d2b97449936acd38eab3ff647a51611.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.554035 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/4-096dd3d409a153d2a5ed7bd08b60095d.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:38.556089 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/team/4@2x-5ced9f369970e95d9911d2086bfa9e05.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:46.679907 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/application-1db2de1e37074e02e740051e7c29ac6f.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:47.716551 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/bootstrap.min-234bbf021d38f070be36df9404f6a96a.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:48.091828 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/custom-4fe1ff2b33f50d974992af0a6ceb97e3.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:48.412493 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/html5shiv.min-d41742a18274b0700292f6237ac3c948.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:48.771216 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/jquery.ajaxchimp.min-8582b331ae23b2cb3eca50cbdcf4bc2b.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:51.004492 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/jquery.min-2487962bfeec97e0d2ba074c95894852.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:51.355807 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/jquery.nav-d46e5e5b49d91d23a68993ff98b77572.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:51.880892 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/jquery.stellar.min-89a3777c5af5bd89c3d7d1c6e08deea4.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:52.371999 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/jquery.videoBG-4ffcad30765dbfb7c328580ae7ead778.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:52.782668 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/nivo-lightbox.min-7ae2b33e351299f0941fa140f396e29a.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:53.426273 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/owl.carousel.min-8ceb5e21d740ea73f80540e3d325bd20.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:53.769731 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/retina.min-e877f5e69e55ab4ab21fbb8d26373f10.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:54.169592 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/smoothscroll-585d3194f57a314a9f0ca9699f830f2f.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:54.785232 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/wow.min-923c95d398c87cb1d98c26f3378e51ac.js
remote:        I, [2015-01-26T17:19:55.736921 #849]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/public/assets/animate.min-7b717bd3f5e5853a80c5037e8c09eccc.css
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "   filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf..."
remote:        (in /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
remote:        (sass):217
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1085:in `expected'
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1080:in `tok!'
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:586:in `block in declaration_or_ruleset'
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `rethrow'
remote:        /tmp/build_fca73891e5cc2d8ca8e9b5267345de50/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:592:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
```

But if I do locally `rake assets:precompile` everything goes fine.

Anybody could tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for a line like

```
filter: progid: DXImageTransform...
```

replace it with

```
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform...";
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be a little bit different on production. you have to do `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` in order to reproduce the behavior from `production` environment.

but regarding to the actual issue - it seems like you might've missed `;` character somewhere in your `application.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a:`rake assets:precompile` locally in your project root and see what happens. You might get a better idea of what's going on.

Could you also look over your application.css as well? You're getting an error here: `Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf..."`

Its coming from your **animate.min** file. See if you can track that down!

Answer (score 0):

me too faced similar error and was able to solve it by searching for line

`filter: progid: DXImageTransform`

in the project folder.

Example:

```
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
```

add quotes as shown below

```
filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";
```

[as mentioned here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/467#issuecomment-295858707)